# Problem during setup of shopware6 on windows

Tags: shopware

I tried to install shopware6 via CLI.

After Execution the following error occurred: `C:\Code\development>./psh.phar '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1):

Windows is no supported OS for shopware. You may want use https://dockware.io/ or use linux.